# Magento how to set attribute seo meta title and description product

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, attribute-set, category-attribute, meta-tags

I have a catalog of 30,000 products on Magento, and I would make sure that the plugin I of seo (free) all products have tag, store name, category name. I turned on the network, to see how to build an attribute, then add the plugin but without results.

[image]

As in the screen, I do not know what attribute inserting in the document, how to create it or create it where this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your products with data (meta title and meta description), then this can be achieved using default Magento `Data Profiles` under `System -> Import/Export -> Data Profiles`.

Helpful Link : http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/content/store-operations/dataflow.html

You don't need all the attributes in CSV, just have SKU and other needed attributes(in your case meta title and meta description).
Make sure to re-configure your mysql and server to run data profile query for these larger number of products otherwise there are chances that it gets stuck in between.

Comment: actually the process crashes. You can have a guide to re-configure the mysql for this type of procedure?